# Anglesharp get node text after DoClick()

Tags: c#, parsing, web-scraping, anglesharp

I have an HTML code:

```
<div class="contact-button link-phone {'path':'phone', 'id':'gtziy', 'id_raw': '243468578'} atClickTracking contact-a"
data-rel="phone">
    <i data-icon="phone"></i>
    <strong class="xx-large">HIDDEN TEXT HERE</strong>
    <span class="spoiler">SHOW</span>
</div>
```

I am getting the div using this code:

```
IHtmlElement nodeToClick = (IHtmlElement)document.All.First(m =>
                    m.HasAttribute("class") &&
                    m.ClassList.Contains("contact-button") &&
                    m.HasAttribute("data-rel") &&
                    m.GetAttribute("data-rel") == "phone");
```

And then I click the node using DoClick():

```
nodeToClick.DoClick();
```

The HTML code of the div should change to this:

```
<div class="contact-button link-phone {'path':'phone', 'id':'gtziy', 'id_raw': '243468578'} atClickTracking contact-a activated"
data-rel="phone">
    <i data-icon="phone"></i>
    <strong class="xx-large">TEXT HERE</strong>
    <span class="spoiler" style="display: none;">SHOW</span>
</div>
```

But the `nodeToClick.TextContent` returns me the same value as it was before `nodeToClick.DoClick()`.

**What I tried to do:**

- Insert a delay `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before logging `nodeToClick.TextContent'
- Rewrite the nodeToClick after a 2 second delay without updating the page
- Reload HTML of the page using this piece of code:

  ```
  public static string GetHTML(string url)
  {
          HttpWebRequest proxy_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

          proxy_request.Method = "GET";
          proxy_request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
          proxy_request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.89 Safari/532.5";
          proxy_request.KeepAlive = true;

          HttpWebResponse resp = proxy_request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
          string html = "";
          using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
          {
              html = sr.ReadToEnd();
              sr.Close();
          }

          resp.Close();

          html = html.Trim();

          return html;
      }
  ```

But **none of this worked for me**.

How do I get the new TextContent of the element I clicked at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused why *anything* should happen when you click a `div`. What you are missing to post is your AngleSharp configuration.

I think you guess that AngleSharp comes with JS support - it does not. AngleSharp itself is just a browser engine core - it comes with all the connection points and the most basic features, e.g., an HTML5 parser. There is another library for bringing JS support - but its very rudimentary / experimental and potentially does not work in your case.

Also I would assume that since you are downloading the HTML in your own code the JS would not work anyway (you need to use AngleSharp like a browser - a browser you also do not give HTML, but an URL and the browser does the rest - with AngleSharp its the same and the thing to use here is called `BrowsingContext`).

Long story short. You cannot just click something static and expect something dynamic to happen. Also you should read the [documentation of AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/docs.html) carefully - I guess it could help.

HTH!